# DNP means to short or keep circuit line open

Tags: pcb-design

In the circuit in image, does the resistor R74 which is DNP mean that the V3P3_7842 connection is left open or connected to the R75 on pin 2?

[image]

Data sheet says that the pin C11 should be tied to GND through 4.7k ohm resistor which has been followed.

My guess is the DNP connection leaves the connection open. Am I right?

Answer (score 9):

It means "Do Not Populate", so R74 is not mounted to the PCB.

R75 is mounted in any case, so it meets what you said is called for (4K7 to GND).

The pin is for testing according to the datasheet so it's unclear why the R74 position is provided- if it's an eval board maybe they actually can test using it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are right.

The acronym means *Do Not Place*, that is, the part won't be placed by the pick and place machine on the PCB.

This means nothing will fill the gap between the pads, or holes, on the PCB, leaving them open (nothing will connect them in any way).

#### EDIT

(to include relevant info that I provided in a comment to answer a doubt of the OP)

Note that even if a part is marked DNP, this doesn't mean it won't *absolutely ever* be placed. If a DNP part should *never ever* be placed, it wouldn't be put in the schematic at all!

The fact that the pads are there means that they *could* be populated, if need arise, but ***the DNP designation refers to the default manufacturing process***.

For example, sometimes that part, another part, or a dead short is placed between those pads for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, but does it mean the connection is shorted or open ?

Comment: @HarshadD If you *do not place* a resistor, would the pads be connected or disconnected? THINK about it!

Comment: I understand that it's supposed to be unconnected an open but in another situation in the same Evaluation board, similar connection has been made to connect the pin to 3.3V. I wonder they would do that. Maybe its' the settings with that other pin. Not sure yet.

Comment: The fact that the pads are there means that they *could* be populated, if need arise (e.g. for testing), but *the DNP designation refers to the default manufacturing process*. If a DNP part should *never ever* be placed, it wouldn't be placed in the schematic at all.

Comment: I just declined a complaint on one of these comments. I wish the system allowed me to say why when I do. In this case the qaim was to educate and taking the advice suggested should improve knowledge.